# Several Knockout model bindings in one DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Let's suppose we have a DOM tree:

```html
<div id="rootNode">
  <span data-bind="..." >

  </span> 

  <div>
     <div> 
        <span data-bind="...">  </span>
     </div>

     <div id="subNode1" > 
        <span data-bind="..." > </span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So we can bind model to that tree

```
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById('rootNode'));
```

But what if we want bind subNode1 to other model? If just write

```
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById('subNode1'));
```

It doesn't work I guess because of first data binding overlap second.

And now why I want to do that. I have a lib with a few independent components which I implemented using Knockout. Components look like this:

```
function ComboBox(container)
{
    this.name = new ko.observable();
    this.someValue1 = new ko.observable();
    this.someValue2 = new ko.observable();

    ko.applyBindings(this, document.getElementById(container));
}
```

And unfortunately I can't write:

```
SomeBigComponent('rootNode');

ComboBox('subNode');
```

How can I resolve that problem? And second question is it good to organize code in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to handle this situation is to create a main view model that is a container for sub-view models.

So, you could have

```
var viewModel = {
  mainModel: { 
     ...
  },
  comboModel: {
     ...
  }
};
```

Then, if you are using 1.3 beta, you would do something like:

```
 <div id="subNode1" data-bind="with: comboModel > 
    <span data-bind="..." > </span>
 </div>
```

Prior to 1.3, you would something like:

```
 <div id="subNode1" data-bind="template: { name: 'comboTmpl', data: comboModel }" ></div>

 <script id="comboTmpl" type="text/html">
    <span data-bind="..." > </span>
 </script>
```

In either case, you would be able to call `ko.applyBindings` once for the entire document.

Comment: But it's very uncomfortable to make libraries which contains varies elements based on knockout, is not?

Comment: You just use your viewModel like a controller and add/remove things that you want Knockout to be aware of.  They can be self-contained entities, you are just adding a reference in the main view model, so that it is available for binding.  Otherwise, you have to bind each model to distinct elements (not descendents of each other).

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass a mode parameter to your view model and based on the mode set a data property which you use for binding, in your ui you will know depending on mode property which ui to make visible, in fact thats a binding in itself

e.g - please have the appropriate/dummy web api methods on the server

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                //allows a view to submit info about a new product
                //and get product data
                function viewModel(mode) {
                    var self = this;
                    self.mode = mode;
                    if (self.mode == 'i') {
        self.data = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS({ ProductID: 0, ShortName:[NEW PRODUCT]', SupplierCode: '', UnitsInBox: 0, CostPerUnit: 0, BoxSalePrice: 0, ImageUrl: '', ProductStores: [] }));
                        self.insert = function (callback) {
                            var d = { value: p };
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "api/productsapi",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: d,
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (d) {
                                    self.d.ProductID = d;
                                    callback();
                                },
                                error: function (e) {
                                    alert("error posting");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.data = ko.observableArray([]);
                        self.loadAll = function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "api/productsapi",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: "{}",
                                type: "GET",
                                success: function (result) {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                        self.data.push(result[i]);
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (err) {
                                    alert("error");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };

                ko.applyBindings(new viewModel('l'));   //change to i for insert

            });
        </script>

        <div id="newprod" data-bind="visible: mode=='i'">
            <span data-bind="text: data().ShortName"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="listing" data-bind="visible: mode=='l'">
            <span data-bind="text: data().length"></span>
            <button data-bind="click: loadAll">Load</button>
        </div>
```